# DataGrid header text alignment in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, headertext

I want to change datagrid header text alignment from left to center.

this is what is used

```
// sample code

var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
tf.size = 15; 
tf.font = "Arial" ;
tf.color = 0x0000FF;
tf.align = "CENTER";

// also tried tf.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;


var room_name:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("Room_Name"); 
room_name.headerText = "Room Name"; 


var minimum_chips:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("Minimum_chips"); 
minimum_chips.headerText = "Minimum Chips"; 

dtgrid.setRendererStyle("textFormat", tf);



  dtgrid.setStyle("headerTextFormat",tf);
  dtgrid.columns = [room_name , minimum_chips];
```

changing any values for text format reflects in header text expect the alignment . I want to set the alignment center. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about change css?

```
DataGrid
{
    headerStyleName:dataGridHeaderStyle;
}

.dataGridHeaderStyle
{
    textAlign:center;
    fontWeight:bold;
}
```

Or if you want to define style at as3, write following code.

```
var newstyle:CSSStyleDeclaration = new CSSStyleDeclaration();
newstyle.setStyle("textAlign", "center");
newstyle.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");

dtgrid.setStyle("headerStyleName", newstyle);
```